# Is Feral Warwick skin bigger?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have purchased Feral Warwick skin at the last discount. When I select it, Warwick looks bigger to my eye. Is it because of colors or is Warwick actually bigger? Most important of all, if it is bigger am I easier to target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Skins do not affect the hitbox of champions.

There are only 3 hitbox sizes in League of Legends, and skins do not change which hitbox a character uses according to this [post](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=7873959#7873959).

[image: The three different hitbox sizes]

Kennen is a small hitbox. Ashe uses a medium hitbox. Cho' Gath uses the large hitbox.

> Thanks for your post! Gameplay hitboxes actually come in three sizes for all champs, >small, medium, and large, and don't change based on things like animations, the model, >or character facing. We do this so that you and your opponents get a consistent >experience.
>
> Galio's wing's aren't actually making his hitbox larger, though he does have a "large" >size hitbox already. As warmonkey and Oluldan pointed out, this both helps Galio tank >and is appropriate given the size of his character.

More information about the three different hitboxes can be found [here](http://www.team-dignitas.net/articles/blogs/League-of-Legends/903/Using-Hitboxes-in-League-of-Legends/). The three special cases are Nasus, Renekton, and Cho'Gath with their ultimates [[Source]](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=7875301#7875301).

> Yes, you are both of course correct, Cho'Gath, Nasus, and Renekton's abilities do cause their hitboxes to increase in size.

Comment: Does Lulus Rampanth Growth increase the size of a champions hitbox?

Comment: @MarkKramer I haven't been able to find an official source but general consensus says yes it does.