# Are there any benefits of a bigger Champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

Related Question: [Is Feral Warwick skin bigger?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/57069/16007)

In the related question, I learned that different champions have different sized "hitbox." I also learned that Chogath, Nasus, and Renekton's ultimates can increase the size of these hitboxes. I also assume surge, greater relic and Wild Growth will also increase this hitbox as it increases the size of the Champion.

My question is, other than the direct benefits that is gained, are there any other benefits of a bigger Champion? To me a bigger Champion means a bigger target to aim for by enemy skillshots.

By direct benefit I mean the skill's direct active buffs.

- Nasus Health Gain, AoE and AD increase
- Renekton Health Gain, AoE, and Fury regeneration
- Cho'gath "permanent" health gain
- Surge's AS and AP increase
- etc...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [..] a bigger Champion means a bigger target to aim for by enemy skillshots.

This is correct, but isn't necessarily a disadvantage.  Most of the characters with large+ hitboxes have more hp, armor, magic resist, etc and are better suited for taking damage.  With a larger hitbox, it's easier to intercept skillshots and other abilities to protect squishier allies.

Also, characters with large hitboxes can stand on "top" of other champions, making them harder to target.

Other than this, I can't think of any direct advantage provided by a larger hitbox.  Spells that increase the hitbox often directly affect the champions stats (think of how Cho'Gath gains HP with each feast), but the size increase itself does nothing.

Comment: Exactly a bigger Hitbox later in the game is very useful. Think of Cho'gath: He will intercept a lot of skillshot and this way he will protect the carry ;)

Comment: If you doubt this point, try playing Ezreal against a team with a tank'Gath.

Comment: A combo I've seen is Hecarim + Lulu. Hecarim build full tank and Lulu uses Rampant Growth on him. Hecarims passive allows teammates to stand inside him and be impossible to hit even with targeted abilities. This is called the Trojan Horse strategy =p

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no benefit from an increased hitbox.

However, there is often an incidental benefit, in that you'll note that only Tanky characters get these size increases in the first place, which means they're more likely to intercept skillshots aimed at their smaller, squishier, brethren.

In the case of Surge / Relic, the size increase helps let them know that they're under the effects of a powerful buff, which might change their targeting or focus strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually bigger champions can slow down or simply block an enemy player (Unless they have ghost) just by standing in the way they want to move to. So if you are bigger it takes more time for them to move around you. Further more being bigger will also give you a higher attack range then other smaller melee characters simply because you are bigger.

Comment: Size has nothing to do with attack range.

Answer (score 0):

Other than hitbox-related points, I guess theres always the **psychological factor.** **Instinctually**, one would be more scared of a **6-stack Cho** than a wild **Kennen**. This is simply because of size. Of course, this instinct is **not a huge advantage** because size does not necessarily translate to strength in this game. But anything counts, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

im pretty sure that size can increase the size of some of your abilities like braums shield etc...